# Is there some way to browse the filesystem of a wordpress bases site?

Tags: css, wordpress, file-browser

A relative has a wordpress based site that they want me to make a few changes to that I can't seem to find a way of doing from wordpress itself because it puts everything in categories but if something doesn't install itself fully or anything you can't find all the files. I want to have some kind of file manager so i can browse the website's filesystem directly, find the files and add the exact code I want to add, and be done with it without removing or disabling wordpress itself.

Comment: Yes, log in using an FTP client.

Comment: I'm really new to website design so I need to know what that is, how I get one, and what to do afterwards

Comment: If you want to learn how to use FTP, go google it. This is not the appropriate forum for this type of help.

Comment: is it an appropriate question though?

Comment: Not appropriate. SE is to help people that are have hit a roadblock with coding. You haven't even started the car. You should know what FTP is and how to use it before you work on it.

Comment: my apologies, I asked here because wordpress has basically no documentation that isn't for people who already know what they are doing, and "file manager for website" just comes up with widgets and themes for wordpress that you install and use your website as a database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use and ftp client to login.  This will allow you to browse the file and folder structure of the server.  Once you get logged in you can use......

dir - directory listing 
cd - change directories 
put add files to the server 
get - pull copies of files from the server

There's more, but this should get you started.